# Can we use google youtube data api without OAuth

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

After reading the documents of Google API. I know that if a project we create needs to access private data, we should use oauth. But here is my situation. we will open a business account in Youtube, and we will create a project to push videos to our own account, we don't need to operate other user's' account. Can we use google youtube data api without OAuth?

Comment: With the help I got from @DalmTo, I created a project that use google node client api to upload video in github. [githubLink](https://github.com/ruhaitsia/timeconsole).  Please take a look if you have same problem with using google oauth2client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to access private user data with Google APIs.

1. Strait [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). where you have a consent for asking the owner of the account if you can access it
2. [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) which are technically pre authorized by the developer.

Normally I would say because you are only accessing the one account that you own, use a service account.  Unfortunately the YouTube API does not support service account authentication.

Due to the lack of service account support you will have to use Oauth2.  I have done this in the past.

Authentication your script once, using a server sided language of some kind.  The Authentication server will return to you a Refresh token.  Refresh tokens can be used at any time to get a new access token.  Access tokens are used to access Google APIs and are only valid for an hour.  Save this refresh token someplace. You will then be able to allow access the YouTube account in question when ever you like.

**Note:** You will have to watch it.  Refresh tokens can on rare occasion become invalid. I recommend having a script ready that will allow you to re authenticate the application again storing a new refresh token.   Its rare that it happens but it can happen best to be pre-paired.

**Oauth Play ground**

Part of the point of Oauth is that it identifies your application to Google though the creation of your project on Google developer console.   Things like quota and access to which APIs is controlled though that.   If you spam the API they will know and shut you down. (never seen this happen)

When you request access of a user it pops up with the name of the project on google developer console.  This is identified by the client id and client secrete for that project on google developer console.    When I use oauth playground I get asked 'Google OAuth 2.0 Playground would like to ..'

So by using playground you are using Googles client id and client secrete to create a refresh token for yourself.  If N other devs are also doing this the quota for YouTube may be used up in the course of a day.  Also security wise you are now giving that project access to your data.   Ignore that for a second what if google suddenly decides to remove change the client id or generate a new one.  Your refresh token will no longer work.   What if random dev X is using it as well and he starts spamming everything and the client id gets shut down (Think this happened last year) your going to have to wait for google to upload a new client id for the one that has now been banned.

Google OAuth 2.0 Playground might seam nice but its not for daily use IMO its good for testing nothing more.  Create your own project and get your own access its not hard just requires a programing language that can handle a http Post.

My tutorial [Google 3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

Comment: I also noticed that Google provides a tool called oauth playground. it can generate refresh token and access token, can I use this tool instead of writing my own script to fetch refresh token?  Long lived refresh code will not be expired, we can use it to generate access token any time we want, right ?

But service account can't be used for Youtube data api really makes things difficult.

Thanks for your help. DalmTo, really appreciate that.

Comment: That ended up being a wall of text sorry :)   I have been doing this for four years now I am happy to help. Might just save you time pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @DalmTo, I watched this video [Generating a refresh token for YouTube API calls using the OAuth playground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeB-zCekGukAo0DzmpwBiua2&index=6) in youtube. We can use our own client id and secret to generate refresh token in oauth playground. 

But yes, I should write my own code to generate refresh token. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: if you can use your own client ID and secrete then I don't see any reason you cant use Oauth playground. your still going to have to code the get access token from refresh token.

Comment: @DaimTo Thanks for your answer!  I was trying to use a Service Account and couldn't figure out why I couldn't find anything but OAuth examples.

Comment: [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/ToG1MsGryHo) helped me to practically apply the technique recommended in this answer