# How do I use the oauth2 access token with the youtube data api

Tags: oauth, access-token, youtube-data-api

I am able to generate an oauth2 access token (from a refresh token), which I believe should give me the ability to access the youtube data api functionally to delete/upload content.

Using python and the youtube api I need to delete and upload a (new) video to youtube periodically, say hourly.

All google python samples I've found seem to call the "DENY/ALLOW" screen which requires a copy/paste back in the calling app.

I can do this occasionally but otherwise want the process to be automated. I've read about service accounts which, which according to the linked post, are not supported by the youtube api.  Offline access et.al. is also mentioned but in somewhat abstract terms i.e. no concrete python examples (that I have yet found). Another source mentioned an http get like below:

"GET access_token=ya29.GlxBBS89....ast987&part=snippet&mine=true"

but the following in python doesn't seem to work returning "response [400]" (bad request)

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels'
args = 'access_token: ' + token var + ', part: snippet, mine: true'
get_token = requests.get(url, data = args)
```

I have used [Can we use google youtube data api without OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733494/can-we-use-google-youtube-data-api-without-oauth) (and others) to get to this stage but need clarification for the next step.

**********************************Update*********************************

I have found that I can only generate access tokens for clients credentials configured as web apps. I am writing a desktop app so I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Or learning Django...

Answer (score 2):

I found examples at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps that helped.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true

curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?access_token=<access_token>&part=snippet&mine=true
```

The curl samples especially provided confirmation that I'm reaching the endpoint and returned helpful debugging info. They have exposed other issues which I'll ask in another question.